# Insert dictionary keys values into a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I have executed this code to insert a dictionary into my table in database,

```
d = {'err': '0', 'tst': '0', 'Type o': 'FTP', 'recip': 'ADMIN', 'id': '101', 'origin': 'REPORT', 'Type recip': 'SMTP', 'date': '2010-01-10 18:47:52'}

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","admin","password","database")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mytable(ID, ERR, TST, DATE, ORIGIN, TYPE_O, RECIP, TYPE_RECIP) VALUES (%(id)s, %(err)s, %(tst)s, %(date)s, %(origin)s, %(Type o)s, %(recip)s, %(Type recip)s)""", d)

db.commit()
db.close()
```

---

Create statement of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
      `ID` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
      `ERR` tinyint NOT NULL,
      `TST` tinyint unsigned  NOT NULL,
      `DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
     `ORIGIN` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `TYPE_O` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     `RECIP` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `TYPE_RECIP` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`DATE`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

But i have an error, it says:

> 1064, "you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to you MySQL server version... )

Comment: It might be the case the argument to cursor.execute is being sent as a raw string.  have you tried forming the string you want in python and then sending the string to sql?

Comment: In `cursor.execute()` function, there seems to be an error caused by invalid string quotations. You may try using double quotes to specify your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware of SQL injections and use the second argument to `execute` for inserting your query parameters:

```
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO
        table
        (name, age, origin, date)
    VALUES
        (%(name)s, %(age)s, %(origin)s, %(date)s)
""", d)
```

Comment: it's stopps at date :/ it only get 20 and it stops and generates and error

Comment: hm, it works for me, what is the type of your table.date field?

Comment: the type of the date field is datetime

Comment: I've created a test table with name, age and origin as `text` fields and date as `datetime` - worked without any errors and the data is there. Could you please edit your question and include the create statement for your table?

Comment: Also, note what error are you getting when you're executing the query I've provided. Thanks.

Comment: ... Actually the table i gave is just an example, actually my table contains much more columns "8", thank you for you time i will edit the question and i'll put the create statement of my table..

Comment: You won't believe it, but your updated code just works without any errors. I'm using python2.7,  mysql 5.5 - though it shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: SO WEIRD HERE'S WHAT I GET :/ 

raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ERR, TST, DATE, ORIGIN, TYPE_O, RECIP, TYPE_RECIP) VALUES ('101', '0', '0', '20' at line 1")

Comment: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type